# Visual Studio 2010 .NET framework 3.5 unavailable

Tags: .net, visual-studio-2008, visual-studio-2010, .net-4.0

I have installed Visual Studio 2010 Professional, and despite my tremendous urge to work on it since it is pleasing to the eye, it seems not to support **.NET framework 3.5/3.0.**

Therefore, I have switched to Visual Studio 2008 rather relunctantly.

How do I add .NET framework 3.0/3.5 to the top right combo box within the **make new project?**

(Note: In the top right combo box within the make new project, I have only .NET framework 4.0 available.)

Comment: Have you actually installed the 3.5 framework?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It should just work absolutely fine - but it depends on the project type. Are you trying to create a Silverlight 4 project or something else that relies on .NET 4?

Try just creating a console application - it should definitely offer .NET 3.5.

I assume you have .NET 3.5 installed?

Comment: well to be brutally honest Jon, this is the thing, I did the following:
-Installed VS 2008
-Found out about VS 2010 and got mega excited and downloaded
-uninstalled VS 2008
-but the .net framework 3.5 was still intact
-i uninstalled framework also thinking about VS 2010
-I installed VS 2010
-There was no frameworks listed except, .NET framework 4.0
-Got furious and installed VS 2008
-Now I have both VS 2008 and VS 2010 + .NET frameworks
-However, in VS 2010 it appears as .NET framework 4.0
-But in VS 2008 it has .NET framework 3.0 and 3.5 and 2.0 
-So i am using VS 2008 [Quite sad I must say]

Comment: If .NET 3.5 is installed, it should certainly give you the option of targeting it. Again, what project type are you creating?

Answer (score 2):

Make sure the 3.5 framework is still installed and hasn't been removed while installing VS2010 with the .NET4 framework. You can donwload the 3.5 framework [here](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyId=333325fd-ae52-4e35-b531-508d977d32a6&displaylang=en)

Answer (score 0):

I've been having the same issue with VS 2010 not having the earlier .NET frameworks available as a dropdownlist inspite of having all the frameworks installed in the machine. After lots of research I found this [link](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/webdevtools/archive/2009/10/12/targeting-earlier-net-frameworks-2-0-3-0-3-5-using-visual-studio-2010-beta2.aspx) to be just right solution for this problem. It turns out that having .NET 3.5, 2.0 or 3.0 is not alone enough, you also have to install .NET 3.5 SP1 for the earlier ones to be available in VS2010. Hope this helps.