# Who is working with VS 2010 professional ? IS it stable as 2008?

Tags: .net, visual-studio-2010

All I want to know is if .NET frameworks 2.0, 3.0 and 3.5 are available in VS 2010 Professional. I have installed VS 2010, but only .NET framework 4.0 is there when making a C# project.

Does anyone else have the same problem ??

I am also working on my Final Year Project. I also would like to know if VS 2010 Professional is stable enough to do my project on image processing. Many of my friends are doing their projects on VS 2008.

Comment: (On a side note, if you **bold** almost everything, nothing stands out as important.)

Comment: Also, why ask the same question if you (according to the accepted answer) have fixed this problem: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2927372/visual-studio-2010-net-framework-3-5-unavailable

Comment: my bad i still had issues i got them figured out now when i installed .NET framework 3.5 sp1

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes. It is as stable.

You can target 2.0, 3.5, 4.0 versions of the .NET framework.

Project->Properties, Application Tab: Target Framework. (you might need to install version 2.0 and 3.5 of the .NET Framework. I can't tell for sure as these were already installed on my PC before installing VS2010).

You can also run VS2008 and VS2010 side-by-side.

Comment: here is the thing i installed VS 2008 it had everything, I saw VS 2010, so i unistalled all frameworks + VS 2008, then I installed VS 2010, then it had .NET framework 4.0 only, I felt so sad so I installed VS 2008 again. This has all frameworks  till 3.5, however VS 2010 has only 4.0 still. I am currently running VS 2010 and VS 2008 side by side. Do you know a way to configure or add .NET frameworks 3.5 or 3.0  to VS 2010 professional.

Comment: If you download the 3.5 .Net Framework and install, then VS2010 should see it.

Comment: You can also run VS2005, VS2008 and VS2010 side by side.

Answer (score 3):

You can target a different framework for your projects in its properties.

I have just swritched to 2010 2 months ago and it is stable and the best IDE from MS so far.

check out [these goodies](http://www.scottlogic.co.uk/blog/gergely/2010/04/ten-cool-things-you-didnt-know-about-visual-studio-2010/) included in vs2010

Mitch brings a good point that you can run 2008 and 2010 side by side (thats what I have been doing)

Comment: here is the thing i installed VS 2008 it had everything, I saw VS 2010, so i unistalled all frameworks + VS 2008, then I installed VS 2010, then it had .NET framework 4.0 only, I felt so sad so I installed VS 2008 again. This has all frameworks  till 3.5, however VS 2010 has only 4.0 still. I am currently running VS 2010 and VS 2008 side by side. Do you know a way to configure or add .NET frameworks 3.5 or 3.0  to VS 2010 professional. Besides i hate 2008, eee. btw y u running it side by side if u think 2010 is stable and it can be made to target certain .NET frameworks like 3.0, y u hav 2008?

Comment: Yeah, you will definitely run into problems if you install vs2010 and then vs2008 after. (Atleast in my experience), Also people have 2008 because this way we can still work on project(s) that were created in 2008 without preparing a new solution...it is less hassle that way!

Comment: Voodoochild try installing .net framework 3.5 sp1 it will all work wit VS 2010 no probs. If u run into a problem in VS 2010 upgrade the version by going to Project -> <solution name> properties -> application tab and upgrade the framework e.g. from 2.0 to 3.5. good luck

Answer (score 1):

Recently installed VS 2010 Premium on Vista Business edition, everything checks out alright, I am getting all versions for target framework.
I also have have VS 2005 and VS 2008 also installed and all of them are still working alright side by side. 
But it took two restarts during the installation wtf.

Comment: You can't be serious TWO reboots? OMG this is not fair .....BUT seriously c'mon 2 reboots to install the frameworks and those IDE is nothing!!!!

Answer (score 1):

Its pretty stable. I've been running it for a month now and I've had one crash in the time.

I usually have a few copies open as our project is split in several apps.

Its not perfect though, there is one annoying bug. If you code to an interface and get an error in an implementation class, when you compile the errors appear then disappear from the error list (not just interfaces, but thats mainly where I see it).

You have to use the output message to get to them.

We have logged this with Microsoft Connect. They came back saying they could not recreate and asked us to video capture, which we did.

Its happening for all of us in the team so it seems to be an issue in visual studio itself.

Its a bit of a memory hog as well, and the wpf ide can be a little clunky, especially for the lads with the slower machines and no hardware graphics card (which 2010 can use to speed up IDE performance).

Comment: Probably should have mentioned this is 2010 ultimate on xp

Comment: Just found another beauty. I have a workstation and laptop open side by side. Did a check in on the workstation, fairly large amount of files, and synched to the laptop (using TFS 2010). The laptop version kept showing compiler warnings that weren't on the workstation.

Turned out if any files were already open on the laptop, the code files had updated but the wpf (I blame wpf anyway, I've nearly really liked anything done in it) code window hadn't refreshed itself. 

I had to close and reopen the code windows to get it to compile.
This is something again I never saw in VS 2003/5/8